# VBA if the value same as specific Dim's name, then get the Dim of value

Tags: excel, vba

how to link `CSVTypeColumn` = `CSVType01` = `"AL"`?
Its has anyway to let if `CSVTypeColumn.value` = `CSVType01` Then `CSVTypeColumn.value` = `"AL"`?

```
'''''Module1
Public CSVType01 As String
       CSVType01 = "AL"

'''''Module2
For CSVTypeColumnCount = 1 To 6
Dim CSVTypeColumn As String                               
    CSVTypeColumn = "CSVType0" & CSVTypeColumnCount
Dim FindCSVType As Range
    Set FindCSVType = .Range(CSVTypeColumn & 1).Column '<-- Wrong here!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not work. When ever you have the feeling you need no use numbers in your variable names then you are doing it wrong!

Use arrays instead.

```
Public CSVType(1 To 6) As String
CSVType(1) = "AL"

CSVTypeColumn = CSVType(CSVTypeColumnCount)
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Use an array:

```
Public CSVType(1 To 6) As String
       CSVType(1) = "AL"
' etc
For CSVTypeColumnCount = 1 To 6
Dim CSVTypeColumn As String                               
    CSVTypeColumn = CSVType(CSVTypeColumnCount)
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you so much :)